# How do I use multiprocessing Pool and Queue together?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need to perform ~18000 somewhat expensive calculations on a supercomputer and I'm trying to figure out how to parallelize the code. I had it mostly working with [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) but it would hang at the .join() step if I did more than ~350 calculations.

One of the computer scientists managing the supercomputer recommended I use [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) instead of Process.

When using Process, I would set up an output Queue and a list of processes, then run and join the processes like this:

```
output = mp.Queue()
processes = [mp.Process(target=some_function,args=(x,output)) for x in some_array]
for p in processes:
    p.start()
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Because `processes` is a list, it is iterable, and I can use `output.get()` inside a list comprehension to get all the results:

```
result = [output.get() for p in processes]
```

**What is the equivalent of this when using a Pool? If the Pool is not iterable, how can I get the output of each process that is inside it?**

Here is my attempt with *dummy* data and a *dummy* calculation:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

##dummy function
def predict(row,output):
    calc = [len(row.c1)**2,len(row.c2)**2]
    output.put([row.c1+' - '+row.c2,sum(calc)])

#dummy data
c = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a','bb'],['ccc','dddd'],['ee','fff'],['gg','hhhh'],['i','jjj']],columns=['c1','c2'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #output queue
    print('initializing output container...')
    output = mp.Manager().Queue()


    #pool of processes
    print('initializing and storing calculations...')
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=5)
    for i,row in c.iterrows(): #try some smaller subsets here
         pool.apply_async(predict,args=(row,output))

    #run processes and keep a counter-->I'm not sure what replaces this with Pool!
    #for p in processes:
    #    p.start()

    ##exit completed processes-->or this!
    #for p in processes:
    #    p.join()

    #pool.close() #is this right?
    #pool.join() #this?

#store each calculation
print('storing output of calculations...')
p = pd.DataFrame([output.get() for p in pool]) ## <-- this is where the code breaks because pool is not iterable
print(p)
```

The output I get is:

```
initializing output container...
initializing and storing calculations...
storing output of calculations...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallel_test.py", line 37, in <module>
    p = pd.DataFrame([output.get() for p in pool]) ## <-- this is where the code breaks because pool is not iterable
TypeError: 'Pool' object is not iterable
```

What I want is for `p` to print and look like:

```
        0   1
0      a - bb   5
1  ccc - dddd  25
2    ee - fff  13
3   gg - hhhh  20
4     i - jjj  10
```

How do I get the output from each calculation instead of just the first one?

Comment: did you try `pool.map()` ? That should take care of the details for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you store all your useful results in the queue `output` you want to fetch the results via calling `output.get()` the number of times it was stored in the `output` (number of training examples - `len(c)` in your case). For me it works if you change the line:

```
print('storing output of calculations...')
p = pd.DataFrame([output.get() for p in pool]) ## <-- this is where the code breaks because pool is not iterable
```

to:

```
print('storing output of calculations...')
    p = pd.DataFrame([output.get() for _ in range(len(c))]) ## <-- no longer breaks
```